# Telerik MVC DatePicker in IE6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid, datepicker, telerik, internet-explorer-6

I am hoping there is someone here who had encountered and solved this problem with Telerik MVC Grid and DatePicker in IE6 (yes IE6! cant do anything as it's the browser used by the client and they are not upgrading anytime soon).

The setup is like this: A Telerik MVC grid using Ajax binding (select, add , edit, and delete). For add and edit, a popup editor is used. The editor template has a Telerik MVC DatePicker.

Telerik demo has the same setup [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/Grid/EditingAjax?theme=vista).Using IE6, the DatePicker disappears after selecting a date.

Comment: I was not able to test the code library submission. I saw it but was not able to get save a copy. Is there anyone who has copy of the javascript?

Comment: In my project, we replaced all Telerik MVC datepicker with jquery date picker but we plan to revert to telerik if the issue fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

[This code library submission](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-mvc/datepicker/fixing-disappearing-datepicker-in-ie6.aspx) was posted pretty recently on Telerik's website and it covers a workaround for disappearing DatePickers in IE6.

Answer (score 0):

The code library is not available any more, but I contacted Telerik on their forum and they said this will be fixed for the next version, due in mid March.